# how to reconnect to redis, when connection is open but not ready?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am using redis(AWS elastic cache) with node and AWS lambdas.

node version - 14
redis library - 4.1.1

```
this.logger.debug(`Is connection open ${this.client.isOpen} ready ${this.client.isReady}`);

returns - Is connection open true ready false
```

since connection is not ready, I am not able to query redis, and I am also not able to call `client.connect/disconnect`. how should I handle this scenario?